# Horizon related question

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

I'm a student taking an undergrad course in physics and we were discussing light and how it works in relation to vision. This question stumped us. What altitude would you need to reach on the globe before the horizon vanished from your view provided you maintained a line of vision parallel to the surface of the earth.

Comment: Is the actual question biology? The basic question is perhaps "What is the vertical field of view of the human eye? Please see [Field of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view). Will the answer be the same for everybody? Or is it the geometry that is causing problems? That would be a math question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, to be fully defined you would need to specify the field of view. The horizon would disappear from a viewpoint "parallel to the surface of the earth" right at the earth unless you have a nonzero angle for your field of view. If your field of view is 180 degrees, you could technically "see" the horizon not matter how high you get, although in reality it would become small and faint.

If you draw a diagram, you should find that the horizon appears at the angle below horizontal given by:

$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{R}{R+h}
$$

for radius of the earth $R$ and height above the ground $h$. Thus, if your field of view is angle $2\theta$

$$
h = \frac{R(1-\cos(\theta))}{\cos(\theta)}
$$

from which you see that when $h = 0$, $\theta = 0$, and as $h$ goes to infinity, $\theta$ goes to a right angle. The limitations on the field of view are thus needed to answer this question exactly.

Note that this is an ideal analysis that assumes no topography and no atmospheric refraction. As you may know if you have ever treated yourself to flat earth material (I actually enjoy solving their "proofs" from time to time), it is actually difficult to see the horizon since the curvature of light due to atmospheric refraction is often of a similar magnitude, and even greater than, the curvature of the earth.

Comment: So if I assumed a 60 degree field of view which apparently is the upper limit for a human I would need to substitute this into the formula to get the height at which the horizon would disappear . This calculation being pre-refraction.

Comment: Assuming the 60 degrees is the half angle (so the field of view is 120), because by "parallel to the surface" you are saying that the individual is looking with the center of the field of view parallel to the surface.

Comment: wouldnt this formula just give the distance to the horizon? Not the height at which it would disappear .

Comment: If you draw the diagram, you will see that this relates the angle below the horizontal of the straight line that lies tangent to the earth, which is basically the horizon. It gives you the height above the earth by subtracting the earth radius. The distance to this apparent horizon point is $(R+h)\cos(\theta)$, which is where the line is tangent to earth. By plugging in $\theta$ as the half angle of the field of view, you can find the height at which the horizon is just at the edge of the field of view. Above this height, the field of view will not cross the earth at all, even tangentially.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of time for editing, but it appears the distance to the horizon is $(R+h)\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle below the horizontal.

Comment: I appreciate your replies greatly by horizontal you mean the radius extended outwards?

Comment: No, I am using the word "horizontal" to mean "parallel to the surface" which would be perpendicular to the radius. As you get higher and higher above the earth, the perpendicular to the radius from the center is still parallel to the surface below you. Again, you should really draw a diagram and convince yourself of all of this.